# Updated parent scope variable not unsetting in child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two controllers and views implemented via ui-view.

```
// This is parent
app.controller('articlesCtrl', ["$scope", "$resource", function($scope, $resource){
  $scope.deck_articles = {};
}]);


// This is child 
app.controller('deckCtrl',[ "$scope", "$location", "Deck", function($scope, $location,   Deck){
   // Here also I use $scope.articles and query the server with it     
}]);
```

In the view, I implemented `ng-click`s that populate `deck_articles` hash and a button that also clears it. (I can see it being cleared by printing out `{{deck_articles}}`)

But even after setting `deck_articles = {}` on pressing clear button, my `deckCtrl` still picks up the whole hash set my `articlesCtrl`.

What am I doing wrong or how do I make sure the changes made in parent are propagated to child too?

Comment: If you don't post the code (preferably providing a fiddle or an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**) how are we supposed to know what you are doing wrong ?

Comment: I think it has to do with ui-view. I realized otherwise its working. Btw my code is in Haml. I'll just post it.

Comment: have you tried scope.$apply()?